# Combine Date and Time from excel into Database

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am trying to have date and time from different columns in excel and write into database. 
For example in the excel having

Date: 23/01/2019

Time: 18:30:00

The result need read and write will be "2019-01-23 18:30:00"
I did google some solutions and tried but still no luck.

Code Sample:

```
start.DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(excelReader.GetDateTime(DatePOS) + " " + excelReader.GetDateTime(TimePOS),"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

DatePOS/TimePOS stand for the column position of Date Column and Time Column 
and I got invalid format error as result. when I check the statement and got

GetDateTime(DatePOS)  "23/01/2019 00:00:00"

GetDateTime(TimePOS)  "30/12/1899 18:30:00"

start.DateTime "1/01/0001 00:00:00"

Please help, thanks

Comment: your date format in `parseExact` is different that the input date. `23/01/2019` & `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` this is year, month and day. the input is day slash month and year.

Comment: `DateTime dateOnly;
DateTime timeOnly;
...
DateTime combined = dateOnly.Date.Add(timeOnly.TimeOfDay); ` before this convert your time span and date to date time then use this logic

Comment: Be aware, `mm` specifier is for minutes, `MM` specifier are for months. Custom date and time specifiers are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `GetString` instead of `GetDateTime`.The latter returns a parsed date from the excel column . Try this

```
start.DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(excelReader.GetString(DatePOS).Split(' ')[0] + " " + excelReader.GetString(TimePOS).Split (' ')[1],
                                     "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Tried, and got exactly same as GetDateTime

Comment: Tried the update again, still same. "1/01/0001 00:00:00"

Comment: I got this working once I changed to "dd/MM/yyyy" from "yyyy-MM-dd", but it only can recognize the time only less than "12:00:00". It will pop errors for time over than"12:00:00" eg."13:00:00". How can it handle 24 hours format?

Comment: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" make it works. Thanks so much.